# MikTeX Icelandic name in BibTeX reference

Tags: bibtex, miktex, icelandic

I am writing a paper and trying to cite an article by Friðriksdóttir. If I remove the icelandic character from the name, it compiles correctly. What can I do so that it can compile correctly and the name of this author is not written incorrectly. I include the top of the article and the error as photos to help.

[image: Packages]

[image]

When the icelandic character is not in but the package is still in existance, the compiler tries to go over every citation asking for something I don't quite understand
[image]

Comment: don't use OT1 encoding, add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: for the second error try deleting bblopts.cfg, texlive has this in the doc tree (`texmf-dist/doc/latex/arabi/bblopts.cfg`) so it only affects the one manual it is intended for but miktex seems to have it in the main input tree. Otherwise provide a real test file for that and provide the error message as text not an image, but a new question as it isn't releated to the icelandic name.